# Pasting a modified Image on to an animated gif using Python PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, discord.py

I'd first like to preface this by mentioning that this is in the context of a Discord Bot which is an Asynchronous environment. To give more context, I'm trying to place a users avatar on top of a given animated gif. The process of which happens like this:

1. Fetch user avatar, store in a BytesIO object.
2. Circularise user avatar using a Mask
3. Iterate a gif and place the avatar in the centre of each frame
4. Recompile into a gif and save into a BytesIO object to be returned.

So far, I have run into two issues, the first being that the avatar is not being placed on each frame so the gif isn't actually modified in any way, the second is that during the saving of the frames back into a gif, I get a MemoryError which I can't seem to fix.

The code used to process the image and gif is here:

```
def processing(avatar_bytes: bytes, background: str) -> BytesIO:
    """Take an image, as bytes, circularise it and then paste onto a gif

    Arguments:
        avatar_bytes: The user's profile picture, as bytes given by `await user.avatar_url_as(format="png").read()`
        background: The location of the background gif as a path.
    """
    with Image.open(BytesIO(avatar_bytes)) as avatar:
        with Image.open(background) as background:
            rgb_avatar = avatar.convert("RGB")

            with Image.new("L", avatar.size) as mask:
                mask_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)

                mask_draw.ellipse([(0, 0), avatar.size], fill=255)

                frames = []
                for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(background):
                    frame.paste(rgb_avatar, (0, 0), mask=mask)
                    frames.append(frame)

            final_buffer = BytesIO()

            print("Memory Error?", len(frames))
            frames[0].save(final_buffer, format="GIF", save_all=True, append_images=frames[1:])

    final_buffer.seek(0)

    return final_buffer
```

The hang seems to occur during the final part where the frames are saved into `final_buffer` so I'm wondering if theres an iterative solution. However, the other issue of the avatar not actually being pasted onto each frame of the gif I need to solve as well. The example gif I'm using is a 500x500px, 100 frame, 310kb file. I've been trawling through the docs and forums for two days now. Help me oh lords of Stack Overflow!

Comment: When you say "the avatar is not being placed on each frame", do you mean that it's not appearing on ANY frame at all (so you end up with basically a copy of the original background GIF), or that it's appearing on some frames but not others?  What are the dimensions, frame count, and file size of the background GIF?

Comment: @jasonharper Yep, its not appearing on any frame. The gif is a 500x500, 100 frame, 310kb file.

Comment: How are you determining that the avatar image didn't get pasted, if the attempt to save the result failed?  Try removing the `save_all=True` from the `.save()`, that shouldn't be needed (it's for saving a single image containing multiple frames, not multiple individual frame images).

Comment: `save_all=False` Gives me a static image, and the other issue of the avatar not being on it still exists. I'm determining that it didn't get saved, by doing an `image.show()` on each frame of the output.